# imnoise('gaussian') underlying equations clarification

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, noise, noise-generator

In MATLAB’s `imnoise()` function, when the type of noise is 'speckle', the documentation clearly states that it is multiplicative noise and states the underlying equation.

> J = imnoise(I,'speckle',v) adds multiplicative noise to the image I, using the equation **J = I+n*I**, where n is uniformly distributed random noise with mean 0 and variance v. The default for v is 0.04.

However, no such equation is provided for the gaussian option. And there is a separate type called 'localvar'. So the equation when using `imnoise(I, gaussian, mean_noise, variance_noise)` should be

> J(x,y) = I(x,y) + g(mean_noise, sqrt((variance_noise))

Further, my assumptions:

1. This noise `g` is not correlated to the spatial coordinates of the image
2. This noise `g` is not correlated to the intensities at those spatial coordinates
3. `g` is a gaussian random number generated from a gaussian distribution of mean `mean_noise` and standard deviation `sigma = sqrt(variance_noise)`

Am I right?

*MAJOR UPDATE*
I am unaccepting the previous answer to clear some confusion.So i checked the code for 'imnoise' in matlab and what it does is:

> b = a + sqrt(p4)*randn(sizeA) + p3;  where
>   b - image with noise added
>   a - original image
>   p4 - variance
>   p3 - mean

What is the range of randn()? I checked randomly and this produces values higher than 1 like 1.85. And the documentation for randn() fails to mention anything about the range. This is quite strange.

Comment: Yes - the Gaussian noise is additive, uncorrelated and "random"

Comment: Well about number 2: If the equation is `J = I+n*I`, then it seems like the magnitude of your noise (in an *additive* sense) is going to be higher where the intensity is higher. However, I'm used to thinking about noise as "*Additive* White Gaussian Noise" (AWGN).

Comment: @Frederick: J = I+n*I is for 'speckle' noise. Not gaussian. In my equation ,the 'g' is not multiplied with I. Also remember matlab alyways reduces I to have intensities in range 0 - 1 before adding noise

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry, just re-read your question and looked at `help imnoise`. Yes, I agree with @RogerRowland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The noise is spatially uncorrelated (i.i.d) and also uncorrelated to the signal. Furthermore, the noise is additive and sampled from a zero-mean unit standard deviation Gaussian which is then scaled for user-provided standard deviation and offset by user-provided mean. If no variance and mean values are specified, imnoise chooses zero mean and 0.01 variance.

You can actually see the entire code for by doing >>edit imnoise in MATLAB. You should have the Image Processing Toolbox.

Regarding randn() - it produces i.i.d samples from a zero-mean unit standard deviation Gaussian. The range of a Gaussian is (-Inf Inf) and hence you see values outside the range (-1 1). MATLAB function rand() gives values in the range (-1 1) that are uniformly distributed.

Edited: Updated answer to include exact default mean and variance values.

Comment: unaccepted the answer. Since i dont think it is a unit standard deviation gaussian, atleast not in all cases. Please see updated question.

Comment: A mathworks forum question, similar: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/280675

Comment: I did not say that the standard deviation of the Gaussian is 1. I said that the noise is sampled from a unit standard deviation zero-mean Gaussian and then scaled to get the standard deviation that the user has specified. If the user does not specify any standard deviation, by default the standard deviation is 0.1 (variance 0.01).     Updating my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

the function imnoise(I, 'gaussian', mean, variance) need the variance normalized between [0 1]. So if your image is of type 'uint8', you should divide the parameter variance by 255².

Note also that the variance is different of the standard deviation sigma. If you would use sigma, you should put (sigma²/255²) as the variance parameter (because variance = sigma²).